# Python, update initialized dictionary that works as class attribute

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I add dynamically new values to a dictionary. When I call it, I am expecting it to be loaded with the recently added values.

```
class Elements():
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.dict = {}
        self.length = length
        self.init_dict()

    def init_dict(self):
        self.dict[0] = self.length
        return self.dict[0]

    def dict_update(self):
        self.dict.update({1: self.dict[0] + 1})
        return self.dict

Elements(100)
print Elements(100).dict
print Elements(100).dict_update()
print Elements(100).dict
```

This returns back:
`{0: 100}, {0: 100, 1: 101}, {0: 100}`

whereas I am expecting
`{0: 100}, {0: 100, 1: 101}, {0: 100, 1: 101}`

Comment: You're making a new object on each line.

Comment: As an aside, don't use `self.dict.update` to update a single value. Use `self.dict[k] = value` so something like `self.dict[1] = self.dict[0] + 1`

Comment: If you want the `dict` attribute to be a class attribute, why not create it as one? Just put `dict = {}` at the class's top level (not inside a method) and remove the equivalent line from `__init__`. Usually that's not what you want, but it seems like it's exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain:

```
Elements(100) # New element created.
print Elements(100).dict # Print dict from a new element created.
print Elements(100).dict_update() # Print what is returned from dict_update from a new element created. In this case, the dict is updated as well.
print Elements(100).dict # Print dict from a new element created. So this object is not related to the old updated one.
```

So you are printing the `dict` value from a newly created object of `Element`, and it is not related to the object you updated.

To fix this problem, you need to refer to 1 object only.

```
ele = Elements(100)
print ele.dict
print ele.dict_update()
print ele.dict
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class Elements():
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.dict = {}
        self.length = length
        self.init_dict()

    def init_dict(self):
        self.dict[0] = self.length
        return self.dict[0]

    def dict_update(self):
        self.dict.update({1: self.dict[0] + 1})
        return self.dict

E = Elements(100)
print E.dict
print E.dict_update()
print E.dict
```